# node-mssql SQL injection warning when executing stored procedure with UPDATE statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, node-mssql

I tried to execute a stored procedure in [node-mssql](https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql) that performs a SQL update:

Javascript code :

```js
const request = new sql.Request();
request.input('name', sql.NVarChar, req.body.name);
request.input('id',  sql.BigInt, req.body.id);
await sql.connect(config);
await request.execute('Update_Name');
```

But the above code returns a SQL injection error:

```json
{
    "code": "EINJECT",
    "name": "RequestError"
}
```

I can't find any reference in the docs on how to negate SQL injections when working with stored procedures?

I'm guessing my input values are the problem? I can't see from the documentation what extra steps I need to take? Or the recommend approach?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the `sp_` prefix is **reserved** by Microsoft and means **S**pecial **P**rocedure. It should not be used for User Procedures. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: Sorry that was only for the example, I will remove

Comment: Does it improve if you use a length specifier? e.g.: `request.input('name', sql.NVarChar(50), req.body.name);` ref: [Data Types](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#data-types)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried specifying the length but still I get the SQL injection error. Thank you for your suggestion, I appreciate you taking the time to ask.